# Problem enabling and paring bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fully upgraded

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I just dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Windows 10. I had a problem enabling the WiFi so i disabled secure boot and it worked. Now I tried fixing the Bluetooth connection. First the Bluetooth was working but can't detect any paired devices. I tried some solutions on the internet nothing worked and I ended up disabling my Bluetooth. So I tried to re-enable it with every solution in the internet with no result. Is there any way I can recover the default Bluetooth settings and search for the solution again, because I think I damaged the setting seriously?

This is the result of the command.

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list bluetooth`?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: 0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
@Kulfy

Comment: @Jeremy31 i'm new to this website i don't know much about editing and stuff

Comment: @anasesg It seems your bluetooth is soft-blocked, i.e. blocked from OS. Try `rfkill unblock bluetooth`. If it doesn't work try `systemctl enable bluetooth.service && systemctl start bluetooth.service`